# How to minus 10 minutes from XMLGregorianCalendar time?

Tags: xmlgregoriancalendar

How to convert current time - 10 minutes to XMLGregorianCalendar in the format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss to a Webservice to fetch records from MDM based on the modified time?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far. The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the FAQ and How to Ask.

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks for your comments. Please find the code below i used as of now to change current time - 10 minutes and then i have converted it into XMLGregorianCalendar Format.

Comment: Date date = new Date();
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10));

System.out.println("Current date post minus 10 minute is:" +currentDate);

XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = null;
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setTime(currentDate);
try{
xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Modified Time in XMLGregorianCalendar format:- " + xmlDate);

Comment: i want to set the webservice with values in the format 8/26/2018 7:37:14 AM UTC.